# Ubuntu is slow and laggy on my laptop

Tags: nvidia, lenovo

I have a laptop Lenovo Legion 5i with specs : 
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10750H @2.60GHz, 
16GB Ram 
Nvidia GeForce GTX 1650 
1 TB HDD 
 
But when I install Ubuntu or any other Linux distribution
It's incredibly slow both to take off and to use
Although the resources of the device are very sufficient to operate it
Although it runs Windows very well

 
Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: NO MODERN OS RUNS ACCEPTABLY WHEN INSTALLED IN AN HDD. This is the main and likely the ONLY problem here. Additional problem may occur if using an old release. For 10th gen Intel ALWAYS use the latest release. Furthermore you need to install Nvidia drivers or, better, enable that option during the installation and either (1) disable Secure Boot in UEFI or (2) use mokutil to sign the Nvidia proprietary drivers. End of story.